# Android SQLite update query error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table in SQLite where I want to update some of the columns. Here is my query:

```
String UPDATE_INFORMATION = "UPDATE " + TABLE_USER + " SET "
            + KEY_ADDRESS_OF_LIVING + " = " + addressOfLiving + ", "
            + KEY_PHONE + " = " + phoneNumber + ", "
            + KEY_IDNP + " = " + IDNP
            + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " = 1";
```

The values in debug:

```
UPDATE user SET address = Efdsdfd, phone = 3797333, idnp = 2006002050245 WHERE id = 1
```

and the error message I get when running this query is:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Efdsdfd
```

Why it takes the **"Efdsdfd"** as column name?

Comment: try this UPDATE user SET 'address' = 'Efdsdfd', 'phone' = '3797333', 'idnp' = '2006002050245' WHERE  'id'=1

Comment: @JineshFrancis ... and why are you quoting the **coulmn names**??????

Comment: Anyway, you can use parametric SQL commands or queries and forget about quoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE user SET address = Efdsdfd, phone = 3797333, idnp = 2006002050245 WHERE id = 1
```

The above query is not valid as address is type of VARCHAR or TEXT. You have to put TEXT values inside single quotes.

**Updated query string:**

```
String UPDATE_INFORMATION = "UPDATE " + TABLE_USER + " SET "
        + KEY_ADDRESS_OF_LIVING + " = '" + addressOfLiving + "', "
        + KEY_PHONE + " = " + phoneNumber + ", "
        + KEY_IDNP + " = " + IDNP
        + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " = 1";
```

**Result will be as**

```
UPDATE user SET address = 'Efdsdfd', phone = 3797333, idnp = 2006002050245 WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to have solved my problem. I will reinstall the app and as one of the columns in my sqlite was not created but most sure it was the problem

Comment: yes! I had to wait 10 minutes until I can accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Or you can use parametric SQL commands or queries and forget about quoting.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing the simple quotes. Remember that when you are setting values for string columns, the values should be surrounded by simple quotes. 
For example :

> UPDATE user SET address = Efdsdfd

should be

> UPDATE user SET address = 'Efdsdfd'

Also my recommendation is that all constants that you use for the database query (simple quotes, commas, data type, etc) should be placed as Constants in a DbHelper or Constants file and not written.

For example:

> String UPDATE_INFORMATION = "UPDATE " + TABLE_USER + " SET "
>               + KEY_ADDRESS_OF_LIVING + " = " + addressOfLiving + ", "

Should be:

> String UPDATE_INFORMATION = "UPDATE " + TABLE_USER + " SET "
>               + KEY_ADDRESS_OF_LIVING + " = " + Helper.SIMPLE_QUOTES + addressOfLiving + Helper.SIMPLE_QUOTES + Helper.COMMA

Comment: Thank you for your response. It would be much easier to write a simple quote that to call the value from a helper class :) The best solution would be to call the SQLite update function rather than running the manual written query, but I do this for testing purposes

Comment: @AndrewT "The best solution would be to call the SQLite update function" i completely agree with you. But who am i to judge) =) . Have a good testing

Comment: Or you can use parametric SQL commands or queries and forget about quoting.

Comment: @Rotwang also true

Answer (score 2):

You have to put TEXT values inside single quotes.

Comment: Or you can use parametric SQL commands or queries and forget about quoting.

Comment: I just wanted to see how to run queries as I will have to perform multiple operations that I will be unable to achieve using queries. But for this query you are completely right!